# Reading native multi select field with ssjs

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

i have a document in readmode and i need a multi select field in it (editable). So i create a something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <select multiple="multiple" name="myField" id="myField" size="3">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <xp:button value="Test" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print(param.get("myField"));}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

When i press the button i got only a value back when i select just one entry, if i select more than one, i got just null back. Is there a trick to got also multiple values from a native html field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the XPages multi-select, but bind it to a view Scope variable. Then you can access that value easily.

```
 <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1"
    value="#{viewScope.someOptions}">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="One" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Two" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Three" itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

That should do the trick for you. YOu then would get an array of values simply by accessing `viewScope.someOptions`. Let us know how it goes

Comment: Of course.. thats a lot better than my solution.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The selected value is contained in the POST data of the HTTP request. You can access the value via *RequestParameterMap* of *ExternalContext*.

Here is an EL statement that will do the trick:

```
<xp:label id="label1" value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestParameterMap.myField}" />
```